# SQL Server Replication subscribers filter

Tags: sql-server, replication, publisher, subscriber

Guys, I have a task to do for my colleague and I need to know if is possible to specify the filter to subscribers when using replication in SQL Server?

What I mean is, I don't want to create 3 types of publishers, each one to each one subscriber (with filter in publisher to redirect to specific subscriber but the inverse.)

I want to indicate to a subscriber the type of data to replicate.

It is possible?

Really Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A certain degree of customization is available in a Merge Replication topology. See: [Filtering Published Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx).

> Parameterized row filters, which are
>   available only with merge replication.
>
> Using parameterized row filters, you
>   can choose a subset of rows to be
>   published. Unlike static filters that
>   send the same subset of rows to every
>   Subscriber, parameterized row filters
>   use a data value supplied by the
>   Subscriber to send Subscribers
>   different subsets of rows.

For an ordinary snapshot or transactional replication, all of your filtering would need to happen on the publisher.